# Кастомизация бордера

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сверстать такую кнопочку?

Comment: ``border-image``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример

```css
button {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: none;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 60px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1;
}

button i {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

button:hover {
  border-color: #00f;
}

button:hover:before {
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button><i class="fas fa-lock"></i>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сначала прописать необходимые стили для самой кнопки (какие вам нужны). Далее задать стили для псевдоэлемента этой кнопки:

```
.btn:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff url();
}
```

Comment: А бордер под картинкой виден не будет? Мне кажется внутри замочка будет бордер проходить. Картинка то png

Comment: отредактировал ответ, посмотрите